# how to configure spring boot with keycloak

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, keycloak

I am using spring boot framework  and angular with keycloak,   i want to add my own privilege from database and use them in @PreAuthorises , but i get a lot of problems with all the configuration i did its not work, i hope you help me or propose me a link to work with it , thanks.

i read a lot of tutorial and the document of keycloak and spring but must of them use only the roles from keycloak token, they explain the basics of the configuration not the implmentation
like this one `https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak`

Comment: The idea behind keycloak is to let you manage your users and roles.

Answer (score 0):

You could wire a `jwtAuthenticationConverter` with a JPA repository to fetch user authorities by user subject (or other user identifier in the token), like I do [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwt-default-jpa-authorities).

But, in my opinion, this is a bad practice as you'll have a request to the database for each and every request on each and every resource server instance.

A much better approach is to write a Keycloak mapper to add this authorities to the tokens. That way, database is accessed only once per token issuance. I do something like that in [this project](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies).

Comment: yes i fount the solution with using jwtAuthenticationConverter but like you said its a bad practice. can you give me more details about the project you did using mappers  i didnt understand it

Comment: It is detailed in project REAMEs: a resource server (REST API) exposes the claims to add ("proxies" in my project, "authorities" in your case), a programmatic client is declared in Keycloak (with dedicated role) to query this API, a custom Keycloak mapper is created. When a token should be created, the custom mapper calls the authorities REST endpoint (using the dedicated programmatic client) and inserts the result in token claims.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answers and your time, but i couldn't  understand how to implement it,